# Status bar becomes black

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have a status bar with style `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`(white text). But when the Application is sent to background, in the task manager, the status bar is shown with black text and it stays black until the application is fully in foreground again (it is black through the whole go to front animation).

I observed this behavior only in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ (simulator and actual device). It shows up white (as expected) on iPhone 4s, 5 and 5s (tested on simulator)

Comment: No, this issue happens on iPhone 5s (device) too.

Comment: @Raptor Not at my app ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25985800/386738). It is a bug which gets solved if the proper splash screens are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps, should be working in iOS 8+ as well.

1) Add property **View controller-based status bar appearance** => **NO** in Info.plist.
2) Add following piece of code in **AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // Change color as per need.

    return YES;
}
```

3) Override method in `ViewController` or you can consider overriding in `ParentViewController` of all `ViewController` if you have such Inheritance hierarchy. Otherwise you have to override this method in every `ViewController`.

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```