# iOS 8: status bar doesn't work with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I've a view with UIImagePickerController..

In the whole application I have:

```
/* white color */
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

But in this case I need to view status bar black, so I set it:

```
/* black color */ 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
```

I've do this in delegate

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

But seems ignoring instruction.

Works only for iOS < 8. I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869178/status-bar-showing-black-text-only-on-iphone-6-ios-8-simulator) question and other, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just change it from your `xib / storyboad` if you want to change for particular view means.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this while presenting UIImagePickerViewController:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem in this way:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if(IS_IOS8_AND_UP) {
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
} else {
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
}

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then in delegate I set the default status bar style.

Hope this help!